# combine items in different list, python

Tags: python

Sorry for the unclear description,I have edited this question.

English is not my native language, so I might express not very good.  :)

I have a list of strings like this:

```
list1=['1A','1B','1C','1D','1E']
list2=['_foo','_bar','_baz','_qux']
_foo=['30','40']
_bar=[]
_baz=['60','70']
_qux=[]
```

I want to iterate through `list1` and `list2`, and match 
the specified item in `_foo` and `_baz`.

In specifically, item in `list2` represents another list. For example, `_foo` which in `list2` is also a list `_foo=['30','40']`.But `_bar` is null.If item in `list2` is not a null list,then mapping the item in `list1` to `list2` and combine them like the output format.

I wish the output like this：

```
1A-30,1A-40,1A-60,1A-70
1B-30,1B-40,1B-60,1B-70
1C-30,1C-40,1C-60,1C-70
1D-30,1D-40,1D-60,1D-70
1E-30,1E-40,1E-60,1E-70
```

Comment: Note that `2A` or `2C` is invalid syntax in Python. And what does `list2` do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python (doesn't matter 2 or 3) you can do something like

```
list1=['1A','1B','1C','1D','1E']
list2=['_foo','_bar','_baz','_qux']
_foo=['30','40']
_bar=[]
_baz=['60','70']
_qux=[]
comb = {}

# NEW
for _i in list2:
    comb[_i] = globals()[_i]

for _i in list1:
    output=[]
    for _j in list2:
        output.extend([_i+'-'+ _k for _k in comb[_j]])
    print(','.join(output))
```

It will return

```
1A-30,1A-40,1A-60,1A-70
1B-30,1B-40,1B-60,1B-70
1C-30,1C-40,1C-60,1C-70
1D-30,1D-40,1D-60,1D-70
1E-30,1E-40,1E-60,1E-70
```

**EDIT**

As you completely changed the problem itself, I agree with @Xavier Combelle, and now this answer is more extension of his answer. What I added is a way to use (local or global) variables instead of hardcode. Check docs for [globals](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) or [locals](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals).

Hope it helps

Comment: I've changed the answer according to the basic requirements. As I said now it is an extension of @Xavier.

Comment: May I says that using `globals` or `locals` is a very bad habit to give.

Comment: @xavierCombelle, I don't see the bad habit in using build-in functions. And the problem was to match list string elements with names of arrays. Not to change variable or do something with it, but just access it.

Answer (score 1):

A general tip is when you want to use variable names as parameters is to use either one list if the variables names are like `var1, var2, var3, ...` or dictionnary otherwise

Here a dictionnay fit the requirements so you can do

```
list1=['1A','1B','1C','1D','1E']
list2=['_foo','_bar','_baz','_qux']
mapping = {"_foo":['30','40'],
           "_bar":[],
           "_baz":['60','70'],
           "_qux":[],}
for primary in list1:
    result = []
    for item2 in list2:
        result.extend([primary+"-"+secondary for secondary in mapping[item2]])
    print(",".join(result))
```

result:

```
1A-30,1A-40,1A-60,1A-70
1B-30,1B-40,1B-60,1B-70
1C-30,1C-40,1C-60,1C-70
1D-30,1D-40,1D-60,1D-70
1E-30,1E-40,1E-60,1E-70
```